# Installing the latest release of QGIS on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I have a bit of experience using QGIS and this software has given me a lot of trouble. I previously downloaded the stable 3.10 release on my Mac and there was a bug with GRASS tools, so I installed the latest release 3.16 on my Mac using the Kyngchaos package, and the GRASS and SAGA tools both did not work. I do not know how to do a clean installation on my mac, I feel like I messed up the installation process and I don't know how to fix it.

I just bought a Windows computer (because I feel it is more compatible with a lot of software) but I am still so hesitant to install QGIS because I do not want to install it improperly.

The installation instructions on QGIS for windows are vague, and I don't know what the difference is between the OSGeo4W network installer and the standalone installers.

Which one is better for me?

I want to be able to access all GRASS tools and SAGA tools, and I want to install plugins like the semi automatic classification plugin.

Do I need to install any software manually (Pthyon, GDAL)?

Perhaps somebody could give me some tips on how to get the most out of QGIS without needing to install a bunch of different software manually. I want to get this installation right the first time around.

Comment: If in doubt, install the standalone version, **NOT** the OSGeo4W network installer. Installing is easy and straightforward, no need to install additional software

Comment: There are several tutorials out there that shows you how to install, e.g. this here: https://youtu.be/ngaeJ_1SDpA or this here https://youtu.be/LDjY-9ucvys and many more

Comment: @Babel Thank you for sharing!! I will take a look at these tutorials.

Comment: QGIS.org also has new .msi (Microsoft Installers) available https://qgis.org/downloads/